# I want to make an icon disapere after some time and I want another icon to take its position after one second delay. I am using font awesome

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

Ok how can I make a font disapere after some time and another icon to take its place with one second delay and this thing should be going on in a loop and I am using font awesome so please help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const switchIcon = (container,newHtml, timeout) => {
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.innerHTML = ''
    setTimeout(() => {
      container.innerHTML = newHtml
    }, 1000)
  }, timeout)
  
}


switchIcon(document.getElementById('icon-container'), '<span> icon 2</span>', 3000)
```

```html
<div id="icon-container">
<span>icon 1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make the animation infinite also can you please add that code also , actually I am a biggner at this.

Answer (score 0):

On top of your css insert

```
    @keyframes icon1 {
      0%   {opacity: 1; z-index: 1000;} 
   /* Change opacity as you like 1= visible 0=not visible, you can also add other % like 20% 10% to make it happen faster and add any css property*/
      50%  {opacity: 0.5;}
      100% {opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
    }
    @keyframes icon2 {
      0%   {opacity: 0; z-index: -1;} /* Change opacity as you like 1= visible 0=not visible */
      50%  {opacity: 0.5;}
      100% {opacity: 1; z-index: 1000;}
    }
    /*If you need it clickable just add z-index or insead of z-index add visibility: hidden when opacity is 0 and visibility: visible to opacity 1*/
    
    then add this to your first icon's css
    animation-name: icon1;
    animation-duration: 4s; //change seconds
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    
    and this to your second icon's css
    animation-name: icon2;
    animation-duration: 4s; /* Change seconds */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

I didn't make it work as you would but you can just change value between them.
you can use absolute position to make them stand on top of each other, remember that position absolute needs top or bottom: (any px you want) px; and left or right: (any px you want) px;. Also set parent to relative.

You can also add transition property to make it smooth, always on icon's css example